# How to export Active Directory 2008 data

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, export

Is there a way to export active directory data using built-in Windows Server 2008 tools?
I want to get the entire tree of OU’s within OU’s in any human-readable format.

Comment: What data do you want, and in what format?

Comment: You need to provide more info on your question as exactly WHAT do you want to export...

Comment: @Spirit : I just did :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the tool you may want to look at is [ldifde](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237677).

It will not export passwords (password hashes) though ([ref](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555634)).  Getting passwords hashes out of the AD is pretty difficult by design.

Comment: As zore mentioned you can use ldifde. heres a sample to get you started ldifde -f exportOu.ldf -s Server1 -d "dc=Export,dc=com" -p subtree -r "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)" -l "cn,objectclass,ou"

Answer (score 2):

I created a series of PowerShell scripts for exporting an AD structure (and then importing them into a test structure.  Those are posted to the [TechNet Script Center](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?query=uslackr&f%5B0%5D.Value=uslackr&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=8) as the copyAD suite and under the ID "uslackr".  Hope that can help.

Comment: You should probably post the script here and then link to the Script Center.

Comment: yes, but there are multiple scripts and they have a license (open source) that could be lost if I paste it here.